# How to update $localstorage data in angularjs 1

Tags: angularjs

How can I update the $localStorage on changing anything get reflected immediate for now it is store data into $localStorage only

```
function _setCurrentUser (user) {
  $localStorage.authUser = user;
  $localStorage.currentProfile = user;
  $rootScope.$broadcast(events.userChanged, user);
}

function getCurrentUser () {
  return $localStorage.authUser;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: localStorage.setItem(obj, value);

Answer (score 1):

`setItem` works for add/update data and `getItem` to get data :

```
$scope.authUser = $localStorage.setItem('authUser',JSON.stringify(user)) // add/update data
$scope.authUser = JSON.parse($localStorage.getItem('authUser')); // Getting data
```

Comment: it says $localStorage.setItem is not a function

Comment: So in your case : Replace $localStorage with $window.localStorage and inject $window as dependency in your controller or services, am sure it should work

Comment: Updated answer, can you check now?

Comment: Just see by `console.log($localStorage.setItem('authUser',JSON.stringify(user)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

`$window.localStorage.setItem(key,value) //to store`

`$window.localStorage.getItem(key) //to retrieve`

`$window.localStorage.removeItem(key) //to remove`